# Microsoft Access database's design: "row source" (in a combo box) and "relationship"

Tags: database, ms-access, combobox, relationship, lookup

I have a small problem during the creation of a database using MS Access. I know that setting right "row source" field (setting "Display control: Combo Box" in "Lookup" label), it is possible to have a Combo Box with the possibilty to choose field from another table (in a many-to-one relationship). For example I have these two tables:

"bank_account":

[image]

"client":

[image]

Having idclient as foreign key of client table. Setting "row source" to this field in this way:

`SELECT client.IDclient, [client].[c_name] FROM client;`

I should have a combobox with the list of "client.c_name" field of "client" table, connected by "IDclient". But I have just a list with "IDclient":

[image]

I would something like that:

[image]

How should I do?

And in "relationship" view, I had to create all the relationships by hand, I thought that in this way were created automatically. However, in "relationship" view I don't have the directions (many, or 1):

[image]

But it is a many-to-one relationship. I would something like that:

[image]

How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're only seeing the IDClient rather than the name is because even though you're using a lookup, you need to be sure you're setting your column count=2 and set the column widths so that the first column is 0cm, second column a suitable amount to display the client name.  There are a host of issues with using lookups, but I won't cover that here.

[image]

As far as relationships go, go to your relationships window, right click on the connection between the tables you have an interest in editing to relationship of, and appropriately select the one-to-many relationship you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks. For the relationship the problem was that I had to click to "Enforce Referencial Integrity"